# failed to open stream: Too many open files in system

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, lumen, sentry

I have implemented APIs in Lumen. deployed to AWS and sentry is integrated with it. somehow since last 2 weeks I am getting below mentioned error randomly

```
ErrorException
include(/var/www/html/vendor/sentry/sentry/src/Integration/RequestFetcher.php): failed to open stream: Too many open files in system
```

[image]

Comment: You can check `ulimit` of your system and increase if needed.

Comment: @Riz should I check it on EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes. Check what the limit is with `ulimit -aS` and which program is the culprit(`lsof | awk '{ print $2; }' | uniq -c | sort -rn | head`) with this command you will get the `pid`(second column) and then you can check with `ps aux|grep $pid` . If it's your app, you can optimize it or increase ulimit.